# Remote Desktop blank screen/timeout in Server 2012

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, azure

I have a Windows Server 2012 box that I RDP into and use throughout the day.  Problem is, when I minimize the remote desktop window or push it into the background for any length of time, the window is blank when I return to it.  Sometimes the window refreshes quickly (in a second), sometimes remote desktop disconnects and then reconnects after a timeout.  This is driving me nuts.

Anyone know why this would be?  Also, this box is running on Windows Azure.  Could it be some sort of firewall/network issue?  Again, everything works wonderfully when I'm actually actively using the machine over RDP.

EDIT: I've changed the inactivity timeout to never and I am still having the problem.  It's arbitrary - sometimes I leave for 30 seconds and I have this problem.

Comment: There is an inactivity timeout on terminal server, I think 15min is default value.

Comment: I've changed the inactivity timeout to never and I am still having the problem.  It's arbitrary - sometimes I leave for 30 seconds and I have this problem.

Comment: Looks like this is a problem with Windows Azure that was fixed on Microsoft's end.

Comment: I have the same problem and I asked it at SF. There is part of the answer. http://serverfault.com/questions/530563/remoteapp-sessions-break-while-beeing-idle-what-can-be-the-cause

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that there is a timeout configured on the server for RDP sessions. I would suggest you look into the the following TechNet article on configuring this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272.aspx

Comment: I set these values using group policy, as I couldn't find a way to change them using Admin Tools.  The termial services snap-ins are missing in Server 2012.  No mention of Remote Desktop anywhere except for the System Properties (where they also live in Windows 7/8).  What gives?